# What are my mistakes when I plot these graphs?

Tags: plot

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=5cm,compat=1.9}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = box,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = {$f(x)$},
]
%Below the red parabola is defined
\addplot [
    domain=-10:10, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
    ]
{x^2 + 2*y^2 - 5 - 44/100};
\addlegendentry{$x^2 + 2*y^2 - 5 - 44/100$}
%Here the blue parabloa is defined
\addplot [
    domain=-10:10, 
    samples=100, 
    color=blue,
    ]
    {x^2 - x*y + y};
\addlegendentry{x^2 - x*y + y}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to plot graphs of these functions:
x^2 + 2*y^2 - 5 - 44/100 = 0 and
x^2 - x*y + y = 0.
Where are my mistakes?

Comment: I have never used it, I took the code from https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/pgfplots_package#Reference_guide and change it a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

You want `addplot3` for this and decrease the number of samples to not exceed TeX memory. You can also use `mesh` or `surf` and the width was too small I used `width=12cm`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=12cm,compat=1.9}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = box,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = {$f(x)$},
]
% Below the red parabola is defined
\addplot3 [
    domain=-10:10, 
    surf,
    %samples=50, 
    color=red,
    ]
{x^2 + 2*y^2 - 5 - 44/100};
\addlegendentry{$x^2 + 2y^2 - 5.44$}
% Here the blue parabloa is defined
\addplot3 [
    domain=-10:10, 
    %samples=50, 
    surf,
    color=blue,
    ]
    {x^2 - x*y + y};
\addlegendentry{$x^2 - xy + y$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The ordering of the plots seems to be totally off. They seem to intersect according to the functions you plot.